# How to resolve ambiguity without backtracking in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr

expr
    :   atom
    |   atom BINARY expr -> ^(BINARY atom expr)
    ;

I would like to resolve this without backtracking if possible. Using backtracking breaks my code for some reason. There isn't a lot of documentation on syntactic predicates, I'm wondering how to do this with predicates instead.

Comment: If ANTLR is complaining about an ambiguity, it originates in another rule. Can you post a complete grammar that reproduces the error you get?

Comment: or try refactoring to this: `expr : (atom -> atom) (BINARY expr -> ^(BINARY atom expr))?;`